# "Те'льное" или "тельно'е"?

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно  говорить: "тЕльное" или "тельнОе"?  Можно ли объяснить правильность ударения "тЕльное", привязывая к "тЕлу"?

Answer (score 1):

Можно, так же как и, например,

> к*У*хонный нож (кУхня)

**UPD** В интернете пишут (да и так известно), что ударения - вещь меняющаяся с течением времени. Почитав про ударения, например, [здесь](http://diktory.com/osobennosti.html), можно сделать вывод, что есть стремление сохранять ударения на основе (существительное или инфинитив, от которого слово произошло), с перемещениями лишь в родах причастий (или отглагольных прилагательных) и глаголов. Благодаря этому можно на слух отличать женский род от среднего, например

> Взять -> взЯл, взялА, взЯло (можно услышать "взЯла", но с женским родом уже не спутается)

Поскольку в нашем случае мы имеем дело с обычным прилагательным `тельное` (не отглагольным и не кратким), то правильно будет сохранить ударение от слова-образователя (`тЕло`): `тЕльное`. Ударение `тельнОе`, безусловно, ярко выделяет принадлежность прилагательного к среднему роду, но это излишне - поскольку вариант `тЕльное` на слух отличается от `тЕльная`.

Comment: Это конечно, так, но вопрос очень принципиальный. Отговоркой: можно так, а можно эдак здесь не обойтись... хочется обоснований, подтверждений источниками...

Comment: Обновил ответ по вашему замечанию. P.S. в вопросе ведь звучало "можно ли", не так ли? )

Comment: Спасибо, очень хорошо аргументировано и, главное, соответствует моему мнению.